# Запятые между однородными членами при разных союзах

Tags: запятые

Например: "Он свободно тебя покалечит или убьёт и свободно поужинает вечером, будто ничего не случилось".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Оснований для запятой нет.**
В Нацкорпусе сотни примеров:

- > ...он носил самодельные круглые значки за тридцать пять копеек, из
  > которых вынимал дурацкие картинки с волком из "Ну, погоди!" или
  > Карлсоном и вставлял вместо них флаг с белой звездой, портрет Луиса
  > Корвалана или Виктора Хары...
- > Время от времени он вскидывал руку и молча, медленно, плавно проводил
  > по волосам ― постоянный жест его, когда он к чему-нибудь прислушивался
  > или ждал и думал.
- > Причина моей неприязни, которую я пытался дурацким образом скрыть,
  > заключалась отнюдь не в пледе или калошах и даже не в Людмиле
  > Сильвестровне...